# Can a database be moved without major disruptions?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Can a live database be moved without major disruptions to users ? Say from Apache server to DigitalOcean ? Or does the site still needs to be put down for maintenance ?

Comment: Yes. And also no. It just depends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-replicated databases people will usually copy the database over, switch the sites, then copy any data from the old db which occured between the time of the first copy and switching over.

Comment: Meaning, if done right, the disruption can be fairly minimal. Perhaps few glitches in short time frame during the process.

Comment: Yes. With larger websites they will have separate servers for the database (many clones but usually one primary database). planning database upgrades is a full time job